# Click on popup (linux)

Tags: linux, watir

I'm a newbie in ruby (and watir).
I try to click on popup (confirm type). All solutions I've found on the net is for windows, what ever I fond requires win32ole (I presume it's for windows).

Is somebody has successfuly clicke on a popup using watir on linux platform ?

Answer (score 0):

I have never attempted this, try using autoit with wine to send key strokes.